# Optimizing: Inline or Macrofunction?

Tags: c++, arrays, optimization

I need to optimize a program as good as somehow possible. Now I came across this issue: I have a one-dimensional array which represents a texture in form of pixel data. I now need to manipulate that data. The array is accessed via the following function:

```
(y * width) + x
```

to have x,y coordinates. Now the question is, what way is the most optimized for this function, I have considered the following two possibilities:

Inline:

```
inline int Coords(x,y) { return (y * width) + x); }
```

Macro:

```
#define COORDS(X,Y) ((Y)*width)+(X)
```

which one is the best practice to use here, or is there a way to get a even more optimized variant of this which I dont know?

Comment: The macro could be faster because it's not passing data, or it could be slower because it takes more room. You have to test the whole program and find out.

Comment: Given that your macro is implemented incorrectly (e.g. try using `1+2` for y), I'd use the function.

Comment: Add one more parentheses around `(Y*width)+x` and replace `x` by `X`. Also add parentheses around `X` and `Y`. So, correct macro will be: `(((Y)*width)+(X))`

Comment: Personally I hate macros refering to variables/objects not local to the macro (width) because that's calling for trouble (unless width is a constant, then it MIGHT be ok).

Comment: width is a constant. It gets defined in the constructor and is never changed

Comment: It is a common misconception that the machine code that comes out of the compiler will be improved by your attempts to prematurely optimise the source code. Write clear, safe code that expresses intent. Trust the compiler to do its job.

Comment: ...full answer posted below to prove why.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani DON'T spread confusion. The macro isn't "passing less data". It's also not "using more room". The compiler compiles both as it sees fit. Most compilers favour fast code (for obvious reasons). Your hint about profiling is right, although in this case it's certainly not required

Comment: @sehe I didn't say "passing less data". That's called a misquote. I said it "could be" faster, it "could be" slower. I am not spreading confusion. Perhaps it's not clear, but I was making a comment, I wasn't writing a book.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani let me be clearer. It's not possible the macro is "faster because it's not passing data". Period.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote a little test program to see what the difference would be between the two approaches.

Here it is:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

static constexpr int width = 100;

inline int Coords(int x, int y) { return (y * width) + x; }
#define COORDS(X,Y) ((Y)*width)+(X)

void fill1(uint8_t* bytes, int height)
{
    for (int x = 0 ; x < width ; ++x) {
        for (int y = 0 ; y < height ; ++y) {
            bytes[Coords(x,y)] = 0;
        }
    }
}

void fill2(uint8_t* bytes, int height)
{
    for (int x = 0 ; x < width ; ++x) {
        for (int y = 0 ; y < height ; ++y) {
            bytes[COORDS(x,y)] = 0;
        }
    }
}

auto main() -> int
{
    uint8_t buf1[100 * 100];
    uint8_t buf2[100 * 100];

    fill1(buf1, 100);
    fill2(buf2, 100);

    // these are here to prevent the compiler from optimising away all the above code.
    copy(begin(buf1), end(buf1), ostream_iterator<char>(cout));
    copy(begin(buf2), end(buf2), ostream_iterator<char>(cout));

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it like this:

```
c++ -S -o intent.s -std=c++1y -O3 intent.cpp
```

and then looked at the source code to see what the compiler would do.

As expected, the compiler completely ignores all attempts by the programmer to optimise, and instead looks solely at the expressed intent, side effects and possibilities of aliases. Then it emits exactly the same code for both functions (which are of course inlined).

relevant parts of the assembly:

```
    .globl  _main
    .align  4, 0x90
_main:                                  ## @main
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp16:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp17:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp18:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    pushq   %r15
    pushq   %r14
    pushq   %r13
    pushq   %r12
    pushq   %rbx
    subq    $20024, %rsp            ## imm = 0x4E38
Ltmp19:
    .cfi_offset %rbx, -56
Ltmp20:
    .cfi_offset %r12, -48
Ltmp21:
    .cfi_offset %r13, -40
Ltmp22:
    .cfi_offset %r14, -32
Ltmp23:
    .cfi_offset %r15, -24
    movq    ___stack_chk_guard@GOTPCREL(%rip), %r15
    movq    (%r15), %r15
    movq    %r15, -48(%rbp)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    xorl    %ecx, %ecx
    .align  4, 0x90
LBB2_1:                                 ## %.lr.ph.us.i
                                        ## =>This Loop Header: Depth=1
                                        ##     Child Loop BB2_2 Depth 2
    leaq    -10048(%rbp,%rcx), %rdx
    movl    $400, %esi              ## imm = 0x190
    .align  4, 0x90
LBB2_2:                                 ##   Parent Loop BB2_1 Depth=1
                                        ## =>  This Inner Loop Header: Depth=2
    movb    $0, -400(%rdx,%rsi)
    movb    $0, -300(%rdx,%rsi)
    movb    $0, -200(%rdx,%rsi)
    movb    $0, -100(%rdx,%rsi)
    movb    $0, (%rdx,%rsi)
    addq    $500, %rsi              ## imm = 0x1F4
    cmpq    $10400, %rsi            ## imm = 0x28A0
    jne LBB2_2
## BB#3:                                ##   in Loop: Header=BB2_1 Depth=1
    incq    %rcx
    cmpq    $100, %rcx
    jne LBB2_1
## BB#4:
    xorl    %r13d, %r13d
    .align  4, 0x90
LBB2_5:                                 ## %.lr.ph.us.i10
                                        ## =>This Loop Header: Depth=1
                                        ##     Child Loop BB2_6 Depth 2
    leaq    -20048(%rbp,%rax), %rcx
    movl    $400, %edx              ## imm = 0x190
    .align  4, 0x90
LBB2_6:                                 ##   Parent Loop BB2_5 Depth=1
                                        ## =>  This Inner Loop Header: Depth=2
    movb    $0, -400(%rcx,%rdx)
    movb    $0, -300(%rcx,%rdx)
    movb    $0, -200(%rcx,%rdx)
    movb    $0, -100(%rcx,%rdx)
    movb    $0, (%rcx,%rdx)
    addq    $500, %rdx              ## imm = 0x1F4
    cmpq    $10400, %rdx            ## imm = 0x28A0
    jne LBB2_6
## BB#7:                                ##   in Loop: Header=BB2_5 Depth=1
    incq    %rax
    cmpq    $100, %rax
    jne LBB2_5
## BB#8:
    movq    __ZNSt3__14coutE@GOTPCREL(%rip), %r14
    leaq    -20049(%rbp), %r12
    xorl    %ebx, %ebx
    .align  4, 0x90
LBB2_9:                                 ## %_ZNSt3__116ostream_iteratorIccNS_11char_traitsIcEEEaSERKc.exit.us.i.i13
                                        ## =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    movb    -10048(%rbp,%r13), %al
    movb    %al, -20049(%rbp)
    movl    $1, %edx
    movq    %r14, %rdi
    movq    %r12, %rsi
    callq   __ZNSt3__124__put_character_sequenceIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIT_T0_EES7_PKS4_m
    incq    %r13
    cmpq    $10000, %r13            ## imm = 0x2710
    jne LBB2_9
## BB#10:
    movq    __ZNSt3__14coutE@GOTPCREL(%rip), %r14
    leaq    -20049(%rbp), %r12
    .align  4, 0x90
LBB2_11:                                ## %_ZNSt3__116ostream_iteratorIccNS_11char_traitsIcEEEaSERKc.exit.us.i.i
                                        ## =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    movb    -20048(%rbp,%rbx), %al
    movb    %al, -20049(%rbp)
    movl    $1, %edx
    movq    %r14, %rdi
    movq    %r12, %rsi
    callq   __ZNSt3__124__put_character_sequenceIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIT_T0_EES7_PKS4_m
    incq    %rbx
    cmpq    $10000, %rbx            ## imm = 0x2710
    jne LBB2_11
## BB#12:                               ## %_ZNSt3__14copyIPhNS_16ostream_iteratorIccNS_11char_traitsIcEEEEEET0_T_S7_S6_.exit
    cmpq    -48(%rbp), %r15
    jne LBB2_14
## BB#13:                               ## %_ZNSt3__14copyIPhNS_16ostream_iteratorIccNS_11char_traitsIcEEEEEET0_T_S7_S6_.exit
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addq    $20024, %rsp            ## imm = 0x4E38
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %r12
    popq    %r13
    popq    %r14
    popq    %r15
    popq    %rbp
    retq
```

Note that without the two calls to copy(..., ostream_iterator...) the compiler surmised that the total effect of the program was nothing and refused to emit any code at all, other than to return 0 from `main()`

Moral of the story: stop trying to do the compiler's job. Get on with yours.

Your job is to express intent as elegantly as you can. That's all.

Comment: Awesome answer! Thank you!

Comment: Although I agree with your conclusion, your test is needlessly complex: all you need to do to prevent the compiler from optimizing your code out is to use command line parameters to calculate Coord() or COORD() and return it. The generated assembly is identical: one imul and one add.

Comment: @VladFeinstein well I guess there are many ways to skin a cat. What I was hoping to show with this demonstration is that the assembler output is *nothing like* the c++ source code. In that sense it worked better than I expected, since the compiler optimised away 2 levels of function calls, unrolled 2 loops and built a cache-efficient way of zeroing out the array. I think the lesson is an important one for young programmers who mistakenly think early optimisation has any merit whatsoever.

Comment: I love this answer -- I'm assuming it was kind of intended to be humorous and you probably knew the conclusion in advance? In any case, perfect answer for this kind of question.

Comment: @Ike glad you liked it. It was fun to write :)

Answer (score 4):

Inline function, for two reasons:

- it's less prone to bugs,
- it lets the compiler decide whether to inline or not, so you don't have to waste time worrying about such trivial things.

Comment: May I offer an edit to your argument? Please remove the word "trivial", because it isn't :)

Answer (score 3):

First job: fix the bugs in the macro.

If you're that concerned, implement both ways using a compiler directive and profile the results.

Change `inline int Coords(x,y)` to `inline int Coords(const x, const y)` so, if the macro version *does* turn out quicker, then the `inline` build version will error if the macro is ever refactored to modify the arguments.

My hunch is that the function will be no slower than the macro in a good optimised build. And a code base without macros is easier to maintain.

If you do end up settling for the macro, then I'd be inclined to pass `width` as a macro argument too for the sake of program stability.

Comment: Hmmm... I like the `const` part, but wouldnt it be even faster  to use `const int & x`?

Comment: I hope the bugs in the OP are fixed now.

Comment: `const int&`: I very much doubt it. `int` is passed by value very quickly as it's normally the "native" integral type on a system.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised that no one mentioned one major difference between a function and a macro: any compiler can inline the function, but not many (if at all) can create a function out of a macro even if that will benefit the performance.

Comment: I think its impossible to create a function out of a macro, as the compiler never "sees" the macro, the precompiler does its work before the compiler does his...

Comment: @Nidhoegger - are you agreeing or arguing? :) My point was - give the compiler a choice, it would know better than you what to do with the function.

Comment: Bit of both I guess. I agree with your argumentation, but also argued to the "but not many"-part, as I guess this is impossible for the compiler (he would need some logic to determin that this codepart is duplicated in the source and outsource it to a function)

Answer (score 0):

I would offer a diverging answer in that this question seems to be looking at the wrong solutions. It's comparing two things that even the most basic optimizer from the 90s (maybe even 80s) should be able to optimize to the same degree (a trivial one-liner function versus a macro).

If you want to improve performance here, you have to compare between solutions that aren't so trivial for the compiler to optimize.

For example, let's say you access the texture in a sequential way. Then you don't need to access a pixel through `(y*w) + x`, you can simply iterate over it sequentially:

```
for (int j=0; j < num_pixels; ++j)
    // do something with pixels[j]
```

In practice I've seen performance benefits with these kinds of loops over the y/x double loop even against the most modern compilers.

Let's say you aren't accessing things perfectly sequentially but can still access adjacent horizontal pixels within a scanline. You might get a performance boost in that case by doing:

```
// Given a particular y value:
Pixel* scanline = pixels + y*w;
for (int x=0; x < w; ++x)
    // do something with scanline[x]
```

If you aren't doing either of these things and need completely random access to an image, maybe you can figure out a way to make your memory access pattern more uniform (accessing more horizontal pixels that would likely be in the same L1 cache line prior to eviction).

Sometimes it can even be worth the cost to transpose the image if that results in the bulk of your subsequent memory access being horizontal within a scanline and not across scanlines (due to spatial locality). It might seem crazy that the cost of transposing an image (basically rotating it 90 degrees and swapping rows with columns) will more than make up for the reduced cost of accessing it afterwards, but accessing memory in an efficient, cache-friendly pattern is a huge deal, and especially in image processing (like the difference between hundreds of millions of pixels per second vs. just millions of pixels per second).

If you can't do any of this and still need random access and you're facing profiler hotspots here, then it might help to split your texture image into smaller tiles (that would mean rendering more textured quads/triangles and possibly even doing extra work to ensure seamless results at the boundaries of each texture tile, but it can balance out and the extra geometry overhead can outweigh the cost if your overhead is in processing the texture). That would be increasing locality of reference and the probability that you'll use more memory cached to faster but smaller memory prior to eviction by actually reducing the size of the texture input you are processing in a totally random-access kind of way.

Any of these techniques can provide a boost in performance -- trying to optimize a one-liner function by using a macro instead is very unlikely to help anything except just make the code harder to maintain. In the best case scenario a macro might improve performance in a completely unoptimized debug build, but that kind of defeats the whole purpose of a debug build which is intended to be easy to debug, and macros are notoriously difficult to debug.